# Responsive container round corners in dart

Tags: flutter, dart, responsive-design, round-corner

I was thinking, in Dart/Flutter, can you insert a responsive value for a radius instead of this fixed value in below line

```
topLeft: Radius.circular(20.0)
```

I wish I can just do somthing like :

```
topLeft: Radius.circular(SOME SECRET CODE HERE JUST LIKE MEDIAQUERY THING THAT GETS RATIO FROM SCREEN SIZE)
```

I have used MediaQuery in

```
 body: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.4,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.6,
),
```

and it perfectly gave me these ratios of the drawn container in respect to screen size, so I need the round corners to inherit specific ratios just like the width and height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create some variables that holds the calculated value of the corners then use a setState to rebuild the screen. So the container will be rebuild with the new value.

```
double leftCornerRadius = 0.0;
//calculate the corner and setstate
setState(){
  leftCornerRadius = 15.0;
}
//and on the container user the variable
topLeft: Radius.circular(leftCornerRadius)
```

So everytime you recalculate the radius using setState will change the radius on the widget.
Hope i could help.

Comment: thanks Jorge

Actually i don't know why i need to setState, only by defining the variable like this

**double leftCornerRadius = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.5;**

then use it in the object like this

**topLeft: Radius.circular(leftCornerRadius)**

it did the job perfectly !

Comment: @RagehElAzzazy hey, good it works, you only need setState if you need change it on runtime, if you only need calc it once then dont need setState. ;)